# Grails createCriteria order by condition on hasMany

Tags: hibernate, sorting, grails, criteria

I'm try to order my createCriteria query by a specific entry of a hasMany.  My domains look like:

```
class Asset {

  String name
  static hasMany = [
    supporters: SupportRole
  ]
}

class SupportRole {
  Asset asset
  Person person
  String role
}

class Person {
  String name
}
```

What I want to do is order my query of Assets by the Person class where role='Primary'.  How do you do a join based on a condition?  I came up with the following query but it doesn't work correctly:

```
assets = Asset.createCriteria.list() {
  supporters {
    like('role', 'Primary')
    person {
      order('name', sortOrder)
    }
  }
}
```

But this query doesn't discern the "role" attribute of the join table, it just eliminates Assets that don't have a 'Primary' SupportRole.  I need it to be able to deal with nulls (e.g., there is no "Primary" SupportRole for the given Asset).

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The criteria can be easily converted to HQL as below where do not have to deal with projections and aliases.

```
def assets = Asset.executeQuery("select a from Asset as a \
                                 inner join a.supporters as s \
                                 inner join s.person as p \
                                 where s.role = 'Primary' \ 
                                 order by p.name = :sortOrder",
                                 [sortOrder: 'desc'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  However, this is part of a bigger query that sorts based on a variable (using jqGrid).  I still need to use criteria for the ability to use variables.  Is there a way to embed this HQL into a criteria?

Comment: Criteria, when run, gets converted to HQL and then executed. When you say "embed HQL into Critera" its not meaningful. Your bigger query can also be written in HQL with some more inner joins wherever associations are used. If you want to know HQL in depth then visit [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html) and see [usage in grails](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeQuery.html). @user1505503

Comment: You can still pass your variables through executeQuery. If your jqGrid is sending the order for example, just put that instead of 'desc'

Answer (score 0):

It's good to use hql is these cases but if you still want to stick with criteria then you should explicitly define the null condition in your query. Let's omit the 'order by' for now and the query should be something like this:

```
assets = Asset.createCriteria.list() {
or{
  supporters {
  like('role', 'Primary')
  }
isEmpty("supporters")
}
}
```